# Why the floating element does not squeeze the inline element?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to study the behavior of css `float`. Here is something wired: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvyne1uq/). I have a container, one inline `span` and two floating `p`:

```
<div id="box1">
    <span>Box 1</span>
    <p id="p1">Paragraph 1</p>
    <p id="p2">Paragraph 2</p>
</div>
```

If the `span` is not there, `p1` and `p2` will be on the same line. However, while `p1` squeezes the `span` to the right, the `p2` is put into the next line!

In my understanding, `p2` should be put at the right of `p1`, and the `span` should be squeezed down to the next line. I have checked the [Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#floats) but cannot find the reason. (Well, maybe I didn't understand the Spec).

What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, if there were no width constraints, `#p1` and `#p2` would both float together with the `span` appearing next to `#p2`.

But because the `span` appears first in the markup, followed by the floating elements, this means the `span` needs to be positioned as high as possible, with the floats following along the same line as the `span` (and subsequent lines if necessary). This line is known as the "current line" in the spec. Here are the relevant quotes from the section you've linked to:

> A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the current line.

> A floated box is shifted to the left or right until its outer edge touches the containing block edge or the outer edge of another float. If there is a line box, the outer top of the floated box is aligned with the top of the current line box.

> Any content in the current line before a floated box is reflowed in the same line on the other side of the float. In other words, if inline-level boxes are placed on the line before a left float is encountered that fits in the remaining line box space, the left float is placed on that line, aligned with the top of the line box, and then the inline-level boxes already on the line are moved accordingly to the right of the float (the right being the other side of the left float) and vice versa for rtl and right floats.

Since there is not enough room to contain both floats *and* the `span` on the same line, this forces `#p2` to be pushed to the next line because there is only enough room to hold `#p1` and the `span` on the first line.

If you widen the container enough, you'll see that both floats will appear on the same line as the `span`. The key here is that the `span` must be as high as possible since it appears before the floats, and then the floats may be no higher (this is mentioned in [section 9.5.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position)):

> 6. The outer top of an element's floating box may not be higher than the top of any line-box containing a box generated by an element earlier in the source document.

Alternatively, if you move the `span` to the end of the container like so:

```
<div id="box1">
    <p id="p1">Paragraph 1</p>
    <p id="p2">Paragraph 2</p>
    <span>Box 1</span>
</div>
```

Then the floats will appear first, with the `span` moving to the next line as there is not enough room to afford it on the same line as the floats.

Comment: So if my understanding is correct, even though the `span` is an inline box, since it comes first in the markup, it insists of being placed in the `current line`. It can tolerate some floated elements to be placed to its right/left, but the first rule is: it should be on the `current line`. Something like http://jsfiddle.net/pvyne1uq/1/. The late floated `#p1` is too wide to be put on the `current line`, so `#p1` is also squeezed to the next line!

Answer (score 0):

I've done several experiments and this is the key to floats as far as inline elements go according to the wonderful statement given by @BoltClock
"**A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the current line.**"

To this I would add that always always always the document source predominates and that when floats are wanted to float to the left/right the inline elements will give them priority by setting to the left/right depending on which side the float element is floating.

[image]

You can see it better if you remove the html and put element by element and see where the current line is going to be.